# How to use Win XP mode,where can I find it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp-mode

I have windows 7 Ultimate 64bit on my laptop and the ultimate version is supposed to have "WinXP Mode"(installed together with os) ,but I can't find it anywhere.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **very** quick web search would have showed you that it is not installed by default, but needs to be installed separately. It can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).

Comment: I can't decide whether I want to keep my answer to try for some reputation or just delete it. Either way +1 for beating me.

Comment: Sorry,I cannot vote up.It requires registration,but if I could,I ensure you I would have voted up both of you.At least I can accept.

Comment: @John - You can't upvote because you don't have 15 reputation. That is the threshhold. You might want to check out the FAQ at the top of the page, it will give you the run-down of how this site works.